# Force virtualenvironment to create an empty environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am new to virtualenvironment and an advanced beginner in python.

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook but it seems that when I create a virtualenvironment the jupyter kernel used is the one of my system and not the one of the virtualenvironment I created.

For this reason I am trying to understand how to create a clean virtualenvironment.

What I do is the following: 
- Create virtualenvironment named `testenv1`:
`virtualenv -p python3 testenv1`
- activate `testenv1`:
`source testenv1/bin/activate`

Here it starts something I don't understand. If I list all the packages installed I have a lot of them already. Is there a way to force a completely clean virtualenv?

Thanks.

```
pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- -------
actionlib                     1.11.13
angles                        1.9.12 
bondpy                        1.8.3  
camera-calibration            1.12.23
camera-calibration-parsers    1.11.13
catkin                        0.7.20 
cv-bridge                     1.12.8 
diagnostic-analysis           1.9.3  
diagnostic-common-diagnostics 1.9.3  
diagnostic-updater            1.9.3  
dynamic-reconfigure           1.5.50 
gazebo-plugins                2.5.19 
gazebo-ros                    2.5.19 
gencpp                        0.6.0  
geneus                        2.2.6  
genlisp                       0.4.16 
genmsg                        0.5.11 
gennodejs                     2.0.1  
genpy                         0.6.7  
image-geometry                1.12.8 
interactive-markers           1.11.5 
joint-state-publisher         1.12.15
laser-geometry                1.6.5  
message-filters               1.12.14
pip                           20.0.2 
pluginlib                     1.11.3 
python-qt-binding             0.3.7  
qt-dotgraph                   0.3.17 
qt-gui                        0.3.17 
qt-gui-cpp                    0.3.17 
qt-gui-py-common              0.3.17 
resource-retriever            1.12.6 
rosbag                        1.12.14
rosboost-cfg                  1.14.6 
rosclean                      1.14.6 
roscreate                     1.14.6 
rosgraph                      1.12.14
roslaunch                     1.12.14
roslib                        1.14.6 
roslint                       0.11.0 
roslz4                        1.12.14
rosmake                       1.14.6 
rosmaster                     1.12.14
rosmsg                        1.12.14
rosnode                       1.12.14
rosparam                      1.12.14
rospy                         1.12.14
rosservice                    1.12.14
rostest                       1.12.14
rostopic                      1.12.14
rosunit                       1.14.6 
roswtf                        1.12.14
rqt-action                    0.4.9  
rqt-bag                       0.4.12 
rqt-bag-plugins               0.4.12 
rqt-console                   0.4.9  
rqt-dep                       0.4.9  
rqt-graph                     0.4.11 
rqt-gui                       0.5.0  
rqt-gui-py                    0.5.0  
rqt-image-view                0.4.14 
rqt-launch                    0.4.8  
rqt-logger-level              0.4.8  
rqt-moveit                    0.5.7  
rqt-msg                       0.4.8  
rqt-nav-view                  0.5.7  
rqt-plot                      0.4.8  
rqt-pose-view                 0.5.8  
rqt-publisher                 0.4.8  
rqt-py-common                 0.5.0  
rqt-py-console                0.4.8  
rqt-reconfigure               0.5.1  
rqt-robot-dashboard           0.5.7  
rqt-robot-monitor             0.5.8  
rqt-robot-steering            0.5.9  
rqt-runtime-monitor           0.5.7  
rqt-rviz                      0.5.10 
rqt-service-caller            0.4.8  
rqt-shell                     0.4.9  
rqt-srv                       0.4.8  
rqt-tf-tree                   0.6.0  
rqt-top                       0.4.8  
rqt-topic                     0.4.11 
rqt-web                       0.4.8  
rviz                          1.12.17
sensor-msgs                   1.12.7 
setuptools                    46.1.3 
smach                         2.0.1  
smach-ros                     2.0.1  
smclib                        1.8.3  
tf                            1.11.9 
tf-conversions                1.11.9 
tf2-geometry-msgs             0.5.20 
tf2-kdl                       0.5.20 
tf2-py                        0.5.20 
tf2-ros                       0.5.20 
topic-tools                   1.12.14
wheel                         0.34.2 
xacro                         1.11.3 
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/schiano/virtualenvs/testenv1/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: What version of `pip` are you using? It used to be that your virtual environment included global packages by default, but that could be disabled with `virtualenv --no-site-packages ...`. Does using that option clear the environment?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. If I do: `virtualenv --no-site-packages testenv2`
I get this error: `virtualenv: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-site-packages`

Comment: Hm. I'll assume that means you are using a new version which actually removed support for that option (which was deprecated and only kept for backwards compatibility; it hasn't actually done anything since the default behavior changed). I am not sure why you are seeing what appears to be all the globally installed packages. If you import one of them inside your virtual environment, what is the module's `__file__` attribute? That will at least tell you where the module is installed, maybe giving you a hint why it's available.

Comment: What I noticed now is that if I install jupyter from my virtualenv (for example) from inside the environment with `pip install ipykernel` and now install a new kernel with `ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname`
it seems that it overrides the jupyter that the virtualenv was "seeing" before.

Comment: Ah, because the virtual environment doesn't prevent you from running binaries (with their own hard-coded Python path) that live outside the virtual environment.

Comment: Yeah, but that's my point. How can I create a virtualenvironment that runs only stuff that lives inside the virtualenv?

Answer (score -1):

Main python installed in your system already have the packages in it. and when you try to create a virtual environment in your system, it create a copy of the main python environment.

you can uninstall all the packages from main python environment by running:

```
pip uninstall <package name>
```

It will ask you for your permission for removal, press y.

or if you want to do it in one go:

```
pip freeze > any_path_on_your_system/requirements.txt

pip uninstall -r any_path_on_your_system/requirements.txt
```

it will ask for your permission  for each uninstall. press y

Install package virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv
```

In this way, all the packages from main python will be removed and then, try your method of creating virtual environment.

reference: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/